# Не запускается браузер при использовании undetected_chromedriver выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

OS Manjaro, python3.11, PyCharm

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service("/usr/bin/undetected-chromedriver")
url = "https://www.avito.ru"
driver = uc.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get(url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

```
File "/home/myname/Рабочий стол/PyCharm_Communiti/Free_Code_Camp/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 453, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

Пробывал и так

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

url = "https://www.avito.ru"
driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=113)
driver.get(url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass

Та же ошибка - текст тот же
Подскажите, как запустить
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, но могу предположить, что service передавать не надо. По сути uc сам должен скачивать хром. Как я решал проблему:
создавал новый экземпляр хрома без каких-либо настроек и спустя неудачных попыток он загрузился

```py
d = uc.Chrome()
d.get("https://google.com")
```

P.s. у меня это ошибка возникала всегда после обновления selenium и самого uc